# How to compare two objects and get different columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two objects of the same record which I am getting from the database. One is before the update, and the other is after the update. I want to know the column values which are changed during this update query.

```
$before_update = DeliveryRun::find($id);
$before_update->name = $request->input('name');
$before_update->save();

$after_update = DeliveryRun::find($id);

compare($before_update, $after_update)
```

Comment: What about using `->getChanges()` ? https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getChanges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define a method on your `DeliveryRun` model which can be used to compare objects of the same type.

Lets say we want to be able to do something like `$deliveryRun->compareTo($otherDeliveryRun)`. That seems like a nice fluid syntax and reads well in my opinion.

What we want to do is get the attributes and their values for the `DeliveryRun` we're calling `compareTo` on and then compare them against the attributes and values for the `DeliveryRun` we provide as an arguement to the `compareTo` method.

```php
class DeliveryRun extends Model
{
    public function compareTo(DeliveryRun $other)
    {
        $attributes = collect($this->getAttributes())
            ->map(function ($attribute, $key) use ($other) {
                if ($attribute != $other->$key) {
                    return $key = $attribute;
                }
        })->reject(function ($attribute, $key) {
            return !$attribute || in_array($key, ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
        });

        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

The above gets the attributes for the current (`$this`) `DeliveryRun`, converts the array returned from `getAttributes()` to a collection so we can use the `map()` function and then loops over each `attribute` on the `DeliveryRun` model comparing the `key` and `value` of each against the `$other` `DeliveryRun` model provided.

The `reject()` call is used to remove `attributes` which are the same and some `attribute` keys which you might not be interested in leaving you just the `attributes` that have changed.

**Update**

> I am saving object in other variable before update `$before_update = $delivery_run;` but after update `$before_update`  variable I also gets updated

If I am understanding you correctly, you're still comparing the same object to itself. Try something like the following.

```php
$before = clone $delivery_run; // use clone to force a copy

$delivery_run->name = 'something';
$delivery_run->save();


$difference = $before->compareTo($delivery_run);
```

I would consider using [`getChanges()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getChanges) as suggested by [@Clément Baconnier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8068675/cl%c3%a9ment-baconnier) if all you're doing is looking to get the changes of an object straight after the object has been saved/updated.

Comment: I am trying to use it like `  dd($delivery_run->compareTo($delivery_run));` but got nothing

Comment: @BilalArshad If you're using it exactly as `dd($delivery_run->compareTo($delivery_run))`, you're comparing the same object to itself. You want to compare `$before` and `$after`.

Comment: you are right but i am saving object in other variable before update ` $before_update = $delivery_run;` but after update `$before_update ` variable i also gets updated

Comment: @BilalArshad I have added an update to my answer to hopefully clarify.

Comment: yes. i tried it but `$before` variable gets updated as you save `$delivery_run`. again it becomes same

Comment: @BilalArshad Ah, I get you now. You're using the exact same object. In which case you can use the [`clone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword to create a copy of an object without it being the same. Answer updated but do consider using `getChanges()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check as well if a property changed from a value to null, I would suggest to set a value when property didn't mutate :

```
class DeliveryRun extends Model
{
    public function compareTo(DeliveryRun $other)
    {
        $attributes = collect($this->getAttributes())
            ->map(function ($attribute, $key) use ($other) {
                return $attribute !== $other->$key ? ($key = $attribute) : 'not updated';
        })->reject(function ($attribute, $key) {
            return $attribute === 'not updated';
        });

        return $attributes;
    }
}
```